# Dynamic update in Entity Framework linq using Table Name

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I'm using .net core and trying to write a generic update method.

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public int TransactionId { get; set; } // primary key
   public string ContextName { get; set; }
   public string TableName { get; set; }
   public int StatusId { get; set; }
   public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to update a record using LINQ

Eg.

```
var entity = [model.ContextName].[model.TableName].Find(model.TransactionId);
var entry = [model.ContextName].Entry(entity);
dbSet.Attach(entity);
entry.Property("StatusId").CurrentValue = model.StatusId;
entry.Property("Comments").CurrentValue = model.Comments;
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
[model.ContextName].SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If this is a desktop application you could keep the context open, load the objects, alter them and use context.SaveChanges() later on. It is designed to keep track of all changes and will persist them

Comment: Update is already dynamic. EF will dynamically generate the UPDATE statement from the entity and the mapping metadata. There's no reason for such code, EF *already* generated all that metadata when the DbContext was created and configured.

Comment: EF is an ORM, not a database connection, model or SQL query builder. Just like all ORMs its job is to Map Objects to Relational tables so your code can work as if it was dealing with in-memory objects instead of a database.

Comment: Updating an object is extremely easy when EF is used properly: `var customer=_context.Customers.Find(customerId); customer.Preferred=true; customer.Addresses.Add(new Address(...)); customer.Comments=comments; _context.SaveChanges();`. It's EF's job to find the correct tables and generate the SQL commands to update both the Customer and related addresses